# Decimal values being rounded when using Float and Decimal data types while importing with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, decimal, rounding, floating-accuracy

I'm new to SQL programming, and am using SQL Server 16.0.1000.6 with SSMS 19 preview 4. I am trying to import a csv flat file into my personal desktop instance of SQL server. Two columns in the flat file - (Total_Charges, and Total_Costs) contain  monetary values and I want to keep those in decimal or numeric format up to two decimal places. I've tried uploading the flat file as a bulk insert, and using the import wizard with the data type set to numeric, decimal and even float and have run with mixed success.

I am experiencing the following problems:

1. While uploading using bulk insert, the decimal values are rounded to the nearest whole integer, irrespective of how the precision and scale values I use for decimal and numeric data types. When I first uploaded using bulk insert and used float data type, the values transferred over as floats, but lately, running the same script yields whole integer values.
2. When I used import wizard and set the values to decimal/numeric, the values transferred over as intended however when i repeated this process, they stopped coming in as decimals and began returning in as integers as described previously

Can anyone explain why I'm experiencing these inconsistencies in results and do you have recommendations for how I can avoid these problems going forward when I need to import data with decimal values?

My representative sample, original source files and scripts/processes I'm using are as follows:

Direct Link to source File:
[Hospital Inpatient Discharges (SPARCS De-Identified) File: 2019](https://health.data.ny.gov/api/views/4ny4-j5zv/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD)

Original Source Page:
https://health.data.ny.gov/Health/Hospital-Inpatient-Discharges-SPARCS-De-Identified/4ny4-j5zv

Representative Sample CSV (Note: the source file was created from unix/linux and has LR carriage return lines):

```
Hospital Service Area,Hospital County,Operating Certificate Number,Permanent Facility Id,Facility Name,Age Group,Zip Code - 3 digits,Gender,Race,Ethnicity,Length of Stay,Type of Admission,Patient Disposition,Discharge Year,CCSR Diagnosis Code,CCSR Diagnosis Description,CCSR Procedure Code,CCSR Procedure Description,APR DRG Code,APR DRG Description,APR MDC Code,APR MDC Description,APR Severity of Illness Code,APR Severity of Illness Description,APR Risk of Mortality,APR Medical Surgical Description,Payment Typology 1,Payment Typology 2,Payment Typology 3,Birth Weight,Emergency Department Indicator,Total Charges,Total Costs
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,30 to 49,106,M,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,2,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,INF008,VIRAL INFECTION,,,723,VIRAL ILLNESS,18,INFECTIOUS AND PARASITIC DISEASES (SYSTEMIC OR UNSPECIFIED SITES),2,Moderate,Minor,Medical,Private Health Insurance,,,,true,26507,4773.11
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,105,F,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,3,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,GEN002,ACUTE AND UNSPECIFIED RENAL FAILURE,,,469,ACUTE KIDNEY INJURY,11,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE KIDNEY AND URINARY TRACT,2,Moderate,Moderate,Medical,Medicare,,,,true,20693,5631.3
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,50 to 69,105,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,7,Elective,Home or Self Care,2019,GEN006,OTHER SPECIFIED AND UNSPECIFIED DISEASES OF KIDNEY AND URETERS,GIS005,EXPLORATION OF PERITONEAL CAVITY,443,KIDNEY & URINARY TRACT PROCEDURES FOR NONMALIGNANCY,11,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE KIDNEY AND URINARY TRACT,4,Extreme,Extreme,Surgical,Medicare,Blue Cross/Blue Shield,,,false,138252,29848.69
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,50 to 69,106,F,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,1,Emergency,Left Against Medical Advice,2019,RSP009,ASTHMA,,,141,ASTHMA,04,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE RESPIRATORY SYSTEM,2,Moderate,Minor,Medical,Medicare,Medicaid,,,true,11799,2595.72
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,105,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,3,Emergency,Psychiatric Hospital or Unit of Hosp,2019,MBD012,SUICIDAL IDEATION/ATTEMPT/INTENTIONAL SELF-HARM,MST007,HIP ARTHROPLASTY,817,OVERDOSE,21,"INJURIES, POISONINGS AND TOXIC EFFECTS OF DRUGS",2,Moderate,Moderate,Medical,Medicare,Private Health Insurance,,,true,52711,11355.62
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,50 to 69,105,M,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,5,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,END003,DIABETES MELLITUS WITH COMPLICATION,MST020,SUBCUTANEOUS TISSUE AND FASCIA EXCISION,344,"OSTEOMYELITIS, SEPTIC ARTHRITIS & OTHER MUSCULOSKELETAL INFECTIONS",08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,2,Moderate,Moderate,Medical,Private Health Insurance,,,,true,51161,12017.19
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,OOS,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,9,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,DIG012,INTESTINAL OBSTRUCTION AND ILEUS,GIS022,GI SYSTEM LYSIS OF ADHESIONS,223,OTHER SMALL & LARGE BOWEL PROCEDURES,06,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE DIGESTIVE SYSTEM,3,Major,Major,Surgical,Medicare,,,,true,96700,18905.83
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,50 to 69,105,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,3,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,RSP002,PNEUMONIA (EXCEPT THAT CAUSED BY TUBERCULOSIS),,,139,OTHER PNEUMONIA,04,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE RESPIRATORY SYSTEM,3,Major,Major,Medical,Medicare,Medicaid,,,true,28909,6740.04
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,50 to 69,106,M,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,1,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,CIR012,NONSPECIFIC CHEST PAIN,,,203,CHEST PAIN,05,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE CIRCULATORY SYSTEM,2,Moderate,Minor,Medical,Medicare,,,,true,26740,5209.08
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,105,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,4,Emergency,Home w/ Home Health Services,2019,SKN001,SKIN AND SUBCUTANEOUS TISSUE INFECTIONS,,,383,CELLULITIS & OTHER SKIN INFECTIONS,09,"DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE SKIN, SUBCUTANEOUS TISSUE AND BREAST",2,Moderate,Moderate,Medical,Medicare,Private Health Insurance,,,true,32346,6999.27
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,106,M,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,2,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,SYM002,FEVER,,,722,FEVER,18,INFECTIOUS AND PARASITIC DISEASES (SYSTEMIC OR UNSPECIFIED SITES),2,Moderate,Minor,Medical,Medicare,Blue Cross/Blue Shield,,,true,16346,4300.71
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,106,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,1,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,DIG012,INTESTINAL OBSTRUCTION AND ILEUS,,,247,INTESTINAL OBSTRUCTION,06,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE DIGESTIVE SYSTEM,3,Major,Major,Medical,Medicare,,,,true,11282,2284.73
Hudson Valley,Westchester,5902001,001045,White Plains Hospital Center,70 or Older,106,M,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,4,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,RSP002,PNEUMONIA (EXCEPT THAT CAUSED BY TUBERCULOSIS),,,139,OTHER PNEUMONIA,04,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE RESPIRATORY SYSTEM,3,Major,Moderate,Medical,Medicare,Private Health Insurance,,,true,38689,9001.06
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,30 to 49,OOS,M,White,Not Span/Hispanic,1,Elective,Home w/ Home Health Services,2019,MUS006,OSTEOARTHRITIS,MST007,HIP ARTHROPLASTY,301,HIP JOINT REPLACEMENT,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,2,Moderate,Minor,Surgical,Private Health Insurance,,,,false,171695.19,27119.19
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,50 to 69,OOS,M,White,Not Span/Hispanic,4,Elective,Home w/ Home Health Services,2019,MUS006,OSTEOARTHRITIS,MST007,HIP ARTHROPLASTY,301,HIP JOINT REPLACEMENT,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,2,Moderate,Minor,Surgical,Private Health Insurance,,,,false,215167.53,40692.52
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,30 to 49,103,M,White,Not Span/Hispanic,7,Elective,Home w/ Home Health Services,2019,INJ037,"COMPLICATION OF OTHER SURGICAL OR MEDICAL CARE, INJURY, INITIAL ENCOUNTER",MST004,INCISION AND DRAINAGE OF MUSCULOSKELETAL TISSUE AND JOINTS,711,"POST-OP, POST-TRAUMA, OTHER DEVICE INFECTIONS W O.R. PROCEDURE",18,INFECTIOUS AND PARASITIC DISEASES (SYSTEMIC OR UNSPECIFIED SITES),3,Major,Major,Surgical,Miscellaneous/Other,Blue Cross/Blue Shield,,,false,104796.21,37762.06
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,30 to 49,112,M,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,1,Elective,Home or Self Care,2019,MUS011,SPONDYLOPATHIES/SPONDYLOARTHROPATHY (INCLUDING INFECTIVE),MST013,SPINE FUSION,321,CERVICAL SPINAL FUSION & OTHER BACK/NECK PROC EXC DISC EXCIS/DECOMP,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,2,Moderate,Minor,Surgical,Private Health Insurance,,,,false,194117.25,31406.84
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,50 to 69,104,F,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,3,Elective,Skilled Nursing Home,2019,INJ035,"COMPLICATION OF INTERNAL ORTHOPEDIC DEVICE OR IMPLANT, INITIAL ENCOUNTER",MST006,KNEE ARTHROPLASTY,302,KNEE JOINT REPLACEMENT,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,2,Moderate,Minor,Surgical,Blue Cross/Blue Shield,,,,false,257171.1,44434.58
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,70 or Older,112,F,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,3,Elective,Skilled Nursing Home,2019,MUS006,OSTEOARTHRITIS,MST006,KNEE ARTHROPLASTY,302,KNEE JOINT REPLACEMENT,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,1,Minor,Minor,Surgical,Medicare,,,,false,104628.37,21668.1
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,50 to 69,113,F,White,Not Span/Hispanic,3,Elective,Home w/ Home Health Services,2019,MUS006,OSTEOARTHRITIS,MST007,HIP ARTHROPLASTY,301,HIP JOINT REPLACEMENT,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,3,Major,Minor,Surgical,Medicaid,,,,false,206263.82,36636.28
New York City,Manhattan,7002053,001446,NYU Langone Orthopedic Hospital,30 to 49,104,F,White,Not Span/Hispanic,2,Elective,Home w/ Home Health Services,2019,MUS006,OSTEOARTHRITIS,MST007,HIP ARTHROPLASTY,301,HIP JOINT REPLACEMENT,08,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE MUSCULOSKELETAL SYSTEM AND CONNECTIVE TISSUE,2,Moderate,Minor,Surgical,Blue Cross/Blue Shield,Blue Cross/Blue Shield,,,false,190443.58,31916.43
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,0 to 17,104,F,Other Race,Spanish/Hispanic,37,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,MBD001,SCHIZOPHRENIA SPECTRUM AND OTHER PSYCHOTIC DISORDERS,MHT001,PHARMACOTHERAPY FOR MENTAL HEALTH (EXCLUDING SUBSTANCE USE),751,MAJOR DEPRESSIVE DISORDERS & OTHER/UNSPECIFIED PSYCHOSES,19,MENTAL DISEASES AND DISORDERS,1,Minor,Minor,Medical,Self-Pay,,,,false,56670.83,37663.43
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,50 to 69,104,M,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,48,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,MBD001,SCHIZOPHRENIA SPECTRUM AND OTHER PSYCHOTIC DISORDERS,MHT001,PHARMACOTHERAPY FOR MENTAL HEALTH (EXCLUDING SUBSTANCE USE),750,SCHIZOPHRENIA,19,MENTAL DISEASES AND DISORDERS,2,Moderate,Minor,Medical,Medicaid,,,,true,68635.76,45615.33
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,50 to 69,100,M,Other Race,Spanish/Hispanic,5,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,MBD017,ALCOHOL-RELATED DISORDERS,SUD001,SUBSTANCE USE DETOXIFICATION,772,ALCOHOL & DRUG DEPENDENCE W REHAB OR REHAB/DETOX THERAPY,20,ALCOHOL/DRUG USE AND ALCOHOL/DRUG INDUCED ORGANIC MENTAL DISORDERS,2,Moderate,Moderate,Medical,Medicaid,,,,true,8008.06,5322.16
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,50 to 69,100,M,Other Race,Not Span/Hispanic,6,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,BLD006,COAGULATION AND HEMORRHAGIC DISORDERS,SUD001,SUBSTANCE USE DETOXIFICATION,661,COAGULATION & PLATELET DISORDERS,16,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE BLOOD AND BLOOD FORMING ORGANS AND IMMUNOLOGICAL DISORDERS,1,Minor,Moderate,Medical,Medicaid,,,,true,38721.94,25734.6
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,30 to 49,112,M,Other Race,Spanish/Hispanic,2,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,MBD017,ALCOHOL-RELATED DISORDERS,SUD001,SUBSTANCE USE DETOXIFICATION,772,ALCOHOL & DRUG DEPENDENCE W REHAB OR REHAB/DETOX THERAPY,20,ALCOHOL/DRUG USE AND ALCOHOL/DRUG INDUCED ORGANIC MENTAL DISORDERS,2,Moderate,Minor,Medical,Medicaid,,,,true,4022.74,2673.51
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,50 to 69,112,F,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,1,Emergency,Home or Self Care,2019,CIR008,HYPERTENSION WITH COMPLICATIONS AND SECONDARY HYPERTENSION,,,199,HYPERTENSION,05,DISEASES AND DISORDERS OF THE CIRCULATORY SYSTEM,2,Moderate,Moderate,Medical,Medicaid,,,,true,11535.34,7666.39
New York City,Manhattan,7002001,001438,Bellevue Hospital Center,30 to 49,100,M,Black/African American,Not Span/Hispanic,39,Emergency,Inpatient Rehabilitation Facility,2019,INJ021,"EFFECT OF OTHER EXTERNAL CAUSES, INITIAL ENCOUNTER",RES007,AIRWAY INTUBATION,792,EXTENSIVE OR PROCEDURES FOR OTHER COMPLICATIONS OF TREATMENT,21,"INJURIES, POISONINGS AND TOXIC EFFECTS OF DRUGS",4,Extreme,Extreme,Surgical,Medicaid,Medicaid,,,true,224350.76,149103.52
```

Scenario 1

Create Table Script (floats):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NYHospitals.dbo.SPARC2019
GO
CREATE TABLE NYhospitals.dbo.SPARC2019
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY, 
        Hospital_Service_Area VARCHAR(15) null,
        Hospital_County VARCHAR(11) null,
        Operating_Certificate_Number VARCHAR(12) null,
        Permanent_Facility_Id INT null,
        Facility_Name VARCHAR(112) null,
        Age_Group VARCHAR(11) null,
        Zip_Code_3_digits VARCHAR(3) null,
        Gender VARCHAR(1) null,
        Race VARCHAR(32) null,
        Ethnicity VARCHAR(20) null,
        Length_of_Stay VARCHAR(5) null,
        Type_of_Admission VARCHAR(15) null,
        Patient_Disposition VARCHAR(37) null,
        Discharge_Year VARCHAR(4) null,
        CCSR_Diagnosis_Code VARCHAR(10) null,
        CCSR_Diagnosis_Description VARCHAR(250) null,
        CCSR_Procedure_Code VARCHAR(10) null,
        CCSR_Procedure_Description VARCHAR(250) null,
        APR_DRG_Code VARCHAR(3) null,
        APR_DRG_Description VARCHAR(500) null,
        APR_MDC_Code VARCHAR(2) null,
        APR_MDC_Description VARCHAR(500) null,
        APR_Severity_of_Illness_Code VARCHAR(1) null,
        APR_Severity_of_Illness_Description VARCHAR(8) null,
        APR_Risk_of_Mortality VARCHAR(8) null,
        APR_Medical_Surgical_Description VARCHAR(14) null,
        Payment_Typology_1 VARCHAR(25) null,
        Payment_Typology_2 VARCHAR(25) null,
        Payment_Typology_3 VARCHAR(25) null,
        Birth_Weight VARCHAR(5) null,
        Emergency_Department_Indicator VARCHAR(12) null,
        Total_Charges float null,
        Total_Costs float null

    )
```

Create View Script (to allow bulk insert to import data through to the table)

```
--Allows data to be passed through it using bulkinsert from flatfile source whose column count does not match destination table SPARC2019.
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.rawdataview
GO
CREATE VIEW rawdataview
AS 
    SELECT 

        Hospital_Service_Area,
        Hospital_County,
        Operating_Certificate_Number,
        Permanent_Facility_Id,
        Facility_Name,
        Age_Group,
        Zip_Code_3_digits,
        Gender,
        Race,
        Ethnicity,
        Length_of_Stay,
        Type_of_Admission,
        Patient_Disposition,
        Discharge_Year,
        CCSR_Diagnosis_Code,
        CCSR_Diagnosis_Description,
        CCSR_Procedure_Code,
        CCSR_Procedure_Description,
        APR_DRG_Code,
        APR_DRG_Description,
        APR_MDC_Code,
        APR_MDC_Description,
        APR_Severity_of_Illness_Code,
        APR_Severity_of_Illness_Description,
        APR_Risk_of_Mortality,
        APR_Medical_Surgical_Description,
        Payment_Typology_1,
        Payment_Typology_2,
        Payment_Typology_3,
        Birth_Weight,
        Emergency_Department_Indicator,
        Total_Charges,
        Total_Costs
    
    FROM dbo.sparc2019
```

Bulk Insert Script

```
USE NYHospitals

BULK INSERT NYHospitals.dbo.rawdataview
FROM 'C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\Hospital_Inpatient_Discharges__SPARCS_De-Identified___2019.csv'
    WITH
        (
        BATCHSIZE = 100000
        ,ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\Hospital_Inpatient_Discharges__SPARCS_De-Identified___2019_ERROR.log'
        ,MAXERRORS = 1
        ,FIRSTROW = 2
        ,KEEPNULLS
        ,FORMAT = 'CSV'
        ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
        ,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
        )
```

[Output after running Bulk Insert Script (float data type)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lNnm.png)

The expected outcome was ex. 190443.58

Scenario 2

Create Table Script (decimal)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NYHospitals.dbo.SPARC2019
GO
CREATE TABLE NYhospitals.dbo.SPARC2019
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY, 
        Hospital_Service_Area VARCHAR(15) null,
        Hospital_County VARCHAR(11) null,
        Operating_Certificate_Number VARCHAR(12) null,
        Permanent_Facility_Id INT null,
        Facility_Name VARCHAR(112) null,
        Age_Group VARCHAR(11) null,
        Zip_Code_3_digits VARCHAR(3) null,
        Gender VARCHAR(1) null,
        Race VARCHAR(32) null,
        Ethnicity VARCHAR(20) null,
        Length_of_Stay VARCHAR(5) null,
        Type_of_Admission VARCHAR(15) null,
        Patient_Disposition VARCHAR(37) null,
        Discharge_Year VARCHAR(4) null,
        CCSR_Diagnosis_Code VARCHAR(10) null,
        CCSR_Diagnosis_Description VARCHAR(250) null,
        CCSR_Procedure_Code VARCHAR(10) null,
        CCSR_Procedure_Description VARCHAR(250) null,
        APR_DRG_Code VARCHAR(3) null,
        APR_DRG_Description VARCHAR(500) null,
        APR_MDC_Code VARCHAR(2) null,
        APR_MDC_Description VARCHAR(500) null,
        APR_Severity_of_Illness_Code VARCHAR(1) null,
        APR_Severity_of_Illness_Description VARCHAR(8) null,
        APR_Risk_of_Mortality VARCHAR(8) null,
        APR_Medical_Surgical_Description VARCHAR(14) null,
        Payment_Typology_1 VARCHAR(25) null,
        Payment_Typology_2 VARCHAR(25) null,
        Payment_Typology_3 VARCHAR(25) null,
        Birth_Weight VARCHAR(5) null,
        Emergency_Department_Indicator VARCHAR(12) null,
        Total_Charges decimal(12,2) null,
        Total_Costs decimal(12,2) null

    )
```

[Output after running Bulk Insert Script (decimal data type)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx3Bv.png)

The expected outcome was ex. 190443.58

Comment: Don't use a `float` and this issue will almost certainly disappear. `float`s are not a precise data type for storing many base 10 values.

Comment: Please include representative sample data as text - I really don't want auto download files cluttering up my pc.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for responding. I've updated the original post to include a sample csv snippet in the code. The original source file was created from linux/unix and contains carriage returns and not the windows CR/LR type.

Comment: @larnu HI larnu, thanks for that information. My original test was with decimal/numeric data type and I was just using float to debug if my SQL Server instance was refusing to import any type of decimal/fraction. FLOAT actually worked the first time I ran it and i saw the expected values up to two decimal places, but subsequent retries results in all the numbers being rounded to nearest integer! I cant explain this.